# Using ngClass for selected value for a background color change

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to change the background color of value selected. I have tried it using ng class and ngmodel but is not working as per expectations. Below is my parent ts file.

```
users = USERS;
selectedUser = 0;
isSelected = false;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

onSelect(index): void {
this.selectedUser = index;
console.log(this.selectedUser);
}
}
```

Below is my parent html file.

```
<div class="row details-container">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" (click)="onSelect(i)" [ngClass]="{select: isSelected}">
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" >
<app-child-detail [(ngModel)]="isSelected" [users]="users[selectedUser]"> 
</app-child-detail>
</div>
</div>
```

Added following in my css file:

```
 .select {
 background-color: black;
 }
```

Following is my child component html file:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
<td><b>Id: </b>{{ users.id }}</td>
<td><b>Name:</b>{{ users.name }}</td>
<td><b>Location:</b>{{ users.location }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use ngclass only for selected value for changing its background

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Comment: yes..thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" (click)="onSelect(i)" 
      [class.selected]="i==selectedUser">
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
```

Basically you need to match selected row index value with `selecteduser` value that you are setting in your `onSelect` method

note : you can use `ngClass` but i user `class.selected` instead of that because there is only one class on that html element.

Answer (score 0):

There's no correct binding for `isSelected`.

This may what you intended:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" (click)="onSelect(i)"
  [ngClass]="{'select': selectedUser == i}">
...
```

Comment: how can I use [ngClass] in this situation

Comment: @pri_91 You can use `[ngClass]="{'select': selectedUser == i}"`. I will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected syntax will be -

```
[ngClass]="{'select': isSelected}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called onSelect method to set index to selectedUser property but have you not set isSelected to true.

Please update the onSelect method as below -

```
onSelect(index): void {
this.selectedUser = index;
this.isSelected=true;
console.log(this.selectedUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using **isSelected**, it doesn't point to any particular item in the array.

You should use comparison operator in the `[ngClass]="{ select: selectedUser === i }"`, here the `i` is the index of the item, when the user clicks the the tr `onSelect(i)` gets invoked with the current item of the array.

So the equal operator compares the `selectedUser` against the index `i`, when it gets matched the `select` class will be added only to that particular item.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" (click)="onSelect(i)" [ngClass]="{select: selectedUser === i}">
....
</tr>
```